# Invalid objectGUID and objectSID shown when importing users from Active Directory to OpenLDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, lsc

I am trying to sync users from Active directory to OpenLDAP using a utility names as lsc-project(http://lsc-project.org/wiki/documentation/start).
There are objectGUID and objectSID attributes are present in Microsoft Active Directory. To map them in OpenLDAP, I have created attributes for both of them:

```
attributetype ( 2.25.128424792425578037463837247958458780603.5
   NAME 'objectGUID'
   EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
   SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
   SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 ) 

attributetype ( 1.26.128424792425578037463837247958458780603.10
   NAME 'objectSid'
   EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
   SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
   SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )
```

But when I am running this utility, there is no error at utility side and in utility logs:

```
objectGUID:: Kck077+9dvvvv71A11+977+977+977+0wqPvv90=
objectSid:: AQUAAAXXAAUVAAXXAO+/vcqgLQYPnO+/ve/+ve+/ve+/vXcEXXA=
```

but in OpenLDAP client (Apache Directory Studio), It shows that:

```
ObjectGuid : Invalid Object GUID
ObjectSid  : Invalid Object SID
```

Any help is appreciable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined the objectGUID and objectSid as Directory String i.e. UTF-8 Strings, however the values above are base64 encoded but the content doesn't look like UTF-8 strings. Hence, Apache Directory Studio cannot read and display them.

Comment: But, When I am using Apache Directory Studio to display Active Directory  details, then it shows objectGUID and objectSID properly. In case of OpenLDAP it shows Invalid  objectGUID and objectSID.
I think I need to change the 'attributetype' structure for both, but I don't know what It should be.